# Visual Studio - templates - No items available for Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I downloaded Visual Studio form https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ 
I am trying to add New File" [Visual C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNXy0.png) " but they are missing it shows No items available for Visual C#,

Comment: That's not the reason the C# templates are  there "Visual C#" templates are  missing

Comment: What modules have you checked to install?

Comment: A screenshot might be helpful, along with details of which workloads are installed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Missing components

- This can be caused by you don't have some components installed.
- when you installed vs. you will get **Visual Studio Installer**. you can find it in win magnet. you can install the components you need.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge and experience. But your answer has a low quality. To help you improve your answers, please read the *[How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*.

Comment: Also [How do I write a good answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: Also [Answering technical questions helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are opening the Folder where the Proyect/Solution is but you are not opening the Proyect/Solution, try open the .csproj file inside the folder you created for the Proyect/Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out my .NET environment installation just magicked itself away somehow

Fixed it with Visual Studio Installer (vs_installer.exe) -> modify -> check .Net enviroment -> install